# How to write an X86 extension

Tags: x86

I was wondering if anyone could point me to any resources or overviews as to how X86 extensions are made. I would like to do research in to how to make a custom extension in a spirit similar to X86-64, as I have an idea that may be worthwhile (which I won't go in to at this time, so don't ask), however I am not sure where to look for information as to how it is done or what to research/learn on how to do it.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Please explain what you mean by an x86 extension. Do you want to create a computer program that runs on a computer or are you wanting to design a piece of hardware?

Comment: er... are you proposing to make your own CPU?

Comment: Well, first you apply for a job at Intel...

Comment: Basically as a gist of what I was thinking of, I was wondering the general concept of how one is created/implemented, I was considering an idea for something, however the more I think about it now that I have read a bit more in to it, it would be best to stick with X86-64, as I was not fully understanding what the functionality of the x86 extensions was. Now that I understand that, it is better for me to stick with X86-64 for my idea, as there really is no point to abandon it, it was just my brainstorming a possibility because I lacked understanding of certain parts of how x86 works.

Comment: Generally speaking, now that I understand a bit further about X86, I really don't see a need to create an extension for it, the idea I had would not need one now that I know more about the functionality of the way extensions work. My question stemmed from a misunderstanding of the architecture system and the purpose of extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Architectures, such as x86 and x86-64, are not written in software, but define the hardware that software runs on. x86 is not just code, but rather, it defines an instruction set, how memory is accessed, registers, etc.

The architecture is part of the processor. You would literally need to design and manufacture a new processor to make a modification to the architecture itself. This is clearly out of reach for most people.

Comment: Alright, understood. I can't go in to details, but as for what you have just explained, that completely tosses my implementation idea in the trash can.

Answer (score 1):

X86 extensions are made by CPU vendors, usually only for their own processor lines. There is no standards body or structural limitations that I know of. You just need some silicon (or emulator) and appropriate opcodes.